# How to copy multiple rows and insert in same table with a primary field in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to copy multiple rows from same table and insert into same table, but table has a column with primary number. So, I am facing problem during insert of multiple copy rows. I am unable to set maxvalue to primary column (`ApplicantExperienceCode`). There is a reason behind copy is, if applicant want to apply again in any vacancy then just click on the old `applicationid` then all old application experience data auto insert into new application experience data.

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicantExperience]
(
    [ApplicantExperienceCode] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DesignationAndPlaceOfPosting] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [NameOfOrganization] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [PayScaleCode] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodFrom] [date] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodTo] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ReportingToDesignation] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [RelevantExperienceDetails] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [SelfDeclarationExpCode] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ActionCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionByCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionIp] [varchar](23) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplicantExperience] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicantExperienceCode] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

my insert query

```
    insert into ApplicantExperience
select * from ApplicantExperience where ApplicationId=5
```

The error message is

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ApplicantExperience'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ApplicantExperience'. The duplicate key value is (7).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: How do you normally handle race conditions when multiple users hit this table at once?  or is this already a problem and doing the multiple consecutive inserts is just making it more apparent? I suppose you could exclusively lock the table, get the max add 1, then use a row number on your results add the max to it insert your records commit and release the lock...

Comment: How do you select the 'Source' rows? Can you post your insert statement here? So we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: This was a fine question, but spoiled by urgent begging and txtspk. Please refrain from adding that to future questions, [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). Thanks!

Comment: Always use explicit field list with `insert` statements.

Comment: thanks to everyone for helping me, i got solution by Mark Karm Sir and it work very fine, Halfer sir, here i always got -ve marks when i asked real life problem, so no probelm. Arvo sir i am using explicit filed, thanks for nice suggestion. Again thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        INSERT into ApplicantExperience
            SELECT 
                ApplicantExperienceCode = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ApplicationId) 
                   + COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ApplicantExperienceCode) FROM ApplicantExperience), 0)
                ,ApplicationId, DesignationAndPlaceOfPosting, NameOfOrganization, PayScaleCode, PeriodFrom, PeriodTo, ReportingToDesignation, RelevantExperienceDetails, SelfDeclarationExpCode, ActionCode, TransactionByCode, TransactionDate, TransactionIp
            from ApplicantExperience 
            where ApplicationId=5
```